# Div is bottomed out after SVG tag

Tags: html, css, svg

HTML:

```
<div id="parent_div">
    <svg id="svg_icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20"><path d="M14.38,3.467l0.232-0.633c0.086-0.226-0.031-0.477-0.264-0.559c-0.229-0.081-0.48,0.033-0.562,0.262l-0.234,0.631C10.695,2.38,7.648,3.89,6.616,6.689l-1.447,3.93l-2.664,1.227c-0.354,0.166-0.337,0.672,0.035,0.805l4.811,1.729c-0.19,1.119,0.445,2.25,1.561,2.65c1.119,0.402,2.341-0.059,2.923-1.039l4.811,1.73c0,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.002,0.002c0.23,0.082,0.484-0.033,0.568-0.262c0.049-0.129,0.029-0.266-0.041-0.377l-1.219-2.586l1.447-3.932C18.435,7.768,17.085,4.676,14.38,3.467 M9.215,16.211c-0.658-0.234-1.054-0.869-1.014-1.523l2.784,0.998C10.588,16.215,9.871,16.447,9.215,16.211 M16.573,10.27l-1.51,4.1c-0.041,0.107-0.037,0.227,0.012,0.33l0.871,1.844l-4.184-1.506l-3.734-1.342l-4.185-1.504l1.864-0.857c0.104-0.049,0.188-0.139,0.229-0.248l1.51-4.098c0.916-2.487,3.708-3.773,6.222-2.868C16.187,5.024,17.489,7.783,16.573,10.27"></path></svg>
    <div id="my_div"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent_div {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 70px;
  height: 52px;
}
#svg_icon {
  background: #900;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
#my_div   {
  background: #090;
  width: 30px;
  height: 22px;
}
```

As you see, green box  (`#my_div`) is bottomed out for several pixels.

Why there  is space between `#svg_icon` and `#my_div` ?

This is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91nah43k/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `height: 52px;` (which limits the height to a fixed value) to `min-height: 52px;` for the parent DIV (to allow the height to grow if the contents require it).

https://jsfiddle.net/0vuz16ad/

To avoid vertical space between the elements, add `display: block` to the SVG element:

https://jsfiddle.net/x6etqjwd/

Comment: This gorws parent div height, but there is still space between children tags

Comment: adding `display: block;` for `#svg_icon` solved problem

Answer (score -2):

put margin to 0px then try if it doesn't work try positioning `position:'relative';top :'10px';`

Comment: You're really providing two answers - why is that? Have you tested these, do they work?, have you tested the answers on the questioner's jsfiddle. Be more specific in your answer. Which margin do you mean, and where would that code go? Same for your option. As it stands, this is not a helpful answer, but only because of how you have presented it.